# Why cannot use compiled Insert statement in Slick

Tags: sql, slick

Slick experts

I'm learning and playing with Slick, and I have question: the document says the Compiled Query only works for select, update and delete, http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/2.0.0/queries.html#compiled-queries

I'm curious why it does not support insert? Does it mean everytime I have to insert a row in the table, the statement needs to be re-compiled by Slick? Is there any way to compile an insert statement? Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The documentation should be clearer here. For inserts you would cache the insert invoker instead.

```
val i = someQuery.insertInvoker
i.insert( foo )
i.insert( bar )
```

The query is only compiled once.

I created a pull request to improve our documentation on this point: https://github.com/slick/slick/pull/629

Comment: Thanks a lot, cvogt! I really didn't pay much attention on the insertInvoker and didn't try that!