# How to convert Rep[T] to T in slick 3.0?

Tags: slick, slick-3.0

I used a code, generated from slick code generator.

My table has more than 22 columns, hence it uses `HList`

It generates 1 type and 1 function:

```
type AccountRow
def AccountRow(uuid: java.util.UUID, providerid: String, email: Option[String], ...):AccountRow
```

How do I write compiled insert code from generated code?

I tried this:

```
val insertAccountQueryCompiled = {

def q(uuid:Rep[UUID], providerId:Rep[String], email:Rep[Option[String]], ...) = Account += AccountRow(uuid, providerId, email, ...)

Compiled(q _)
}
```

I need to convert `Rep[T]` to `T` for **AccountRow** function to work. How do I do that?

Thank you

Comment: Were you able to find answer to this?

Comment: This might be of help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21422394/why-cannot-use-compiled-insert-statement-in-slick

Answer (score 1):

**;TLDR;** Not possible

**Explanation**

There are two levels of abstraction in Slick: `Query`s and `DBIOAction`s.

When you're dealing with `Query`s, you have to access your schema definitions, and rows, `Rep`s and, basically, it's very constrained as it's the closest level of abstraction to the actual DB you're using. A `Rep` refers to an hypothetical value in the database, not in your program.

Then you have DBIOActions, which are the next level... not just some definition of a query, but the execution of it. You usually get `DBIOAction`s when getting information out of a query, like with the `result` method or (TADAN!) when inserting rows.

`Insert`s and `Update`s are not queries and so what you're trying to do is not possible. You're dealing with DBIOAction (the `+=` method), and `Query` stuff (the `Rep` types). The only way to get a Rep inside a DBIOAction is by executing a Query and obtaining a DBIOAction and then composing both Actions using `flatMap` or for comprehensions (which is the same).